# calculate difference of two calculated fields

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query, which basically gets the average spend of a customer over the last year, and 3 months:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS 
       customer_id,
       customer_name,
       AVG(IF(
            DATE(CONCAT(year_of_spend, "-", month_of_spend, "-01")) >=
                DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR, "%Y-%m-01"),
            spend_amount,
            NULL
       )) AS 1_year_average_spend,
       AVG(IF(
            DATE(CONCAT(year_of_spend, "-", month_of_spend, "-01")) >=
                DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH, "%Y-%m-01"),
            spend_amount,
            NULL
       )) AS 3_month_average_spend

FROM   customer_spends
GROUP  BY customer__id
```

But I also need to get the percent difference of the  spend averages:

E.g. (pseudo code)

```
if (1_year_average_spend = 0)
    change = N/A
else 
    change = 3_month_average_spend / 1_year_average_spend - 1
```

How can, or what do you recommend I do to implement this?

The only way I can think of is horrible:

```
IF(
    AVG(IF(
            DATE(CONCAT(year_of_spend, "-", month_of_spend, "-01")) >=
                DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR, "%Y-%m-01"),
            `spend_amount`,
            NULL
    )) > 0,
    AVG(IF(
            DATE(CONCAT(year_of_spend, "-", month_of_spend, "-01")) >=
                DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH, "%Y-%m-01"),
            spend_amount,
            NULL
    )) / AVG(IF(
            DATE(CONCAT(year_of_spend, "-", month_of_spend, "-01")) >=
                DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR, "%Y-%m-01"),
            `spend_amount`,
            NULL
    )) - 1,
    "N/A"
) AS 3_month_performance
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are happy to use MySQL specific code, you can use [User-Defined Variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/user-variables.html) like this (simplified version):

```
SELECT @avg1 := ROUND((1 + 2 + 3) / 3, 2) AS avg1,
       @avg2 := ROUND((4 + 5 + 6) / 3, 2) AS avg2,
   IF( @avg1, ROUND(@avg2 / @avg1 - 1, 2), NULL ) AS result;

+------+------+--------+
| avg1 | avg2 | result |
+------+------+--------+
| 2.00 | 5.00 |   1.50 |
+------+------+--------+
```

That would become:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS 
       customer_id,
       customer_name,
       @1_year_average_spend := AVG(IF(
            DATE(CONCAT(year_of_spend, "-", month_of_spend, "-01")) >=
                DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR, "%Y-%m-01"),
            spend_amount,
            NULL
       )) AS 1_year_average_spend,
       @3_month_average_spend := AVG(IF(
            DATE(CONCAT(year_of_spend, "-", month_of_spend, "-01")) >=
                DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH, "%Y-%m-01"),
            spend_amount,
            NULL
       )) AS 3_month_average_spend,
       IF( @1_year_average_spend,
           @3_month_average_spend / @1_year_average_spend - 1,
           NULL
       ) AS diff

FROM   customer_spends
GROUP  BY customer__id
```

**Note 1:** I've used `diff` as the column name for the difference, as `change` is a reserved word, so may end up causing problems.

**Note 2:** You need to be aware of the following caveats from the docs, as they may affect your result:

> Assignment of decimal and real values does not preserve the precision
>   or scale of the value.

And:

> As a general rule, you should never assign a value to a user variable
>   and read the value within the same statement. You might get the
>   results you expect, but this is not guaranteed. The order of
>   evaluation for expressions involving user variables is undefined and
>   may change based on the elements contained within a given statement.
>   In SELECT @a, @a:=@a+1, ..., you might think that MySQL will evaluate
>   @a first and then do an assignment second. However, changing the
>   statement (for example, by adding a GROUP BY, HAVING, or ORDER BY
>   clause) may cause MySQL to select an execution plan with a different
>   order of evaluation.

So use with caution, and proper testing!

Comment: Thats strange, I edited my post hours ago after I relised `change` was reserved, but other than that weird fact, +1

Comment: @Petah: It's probably worth mentioning that I (and [people with far more knowledge on the subject](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/15/advanced-mysql-user-variable-techniques/)) have used variables like this without problems on many occasions.  So the caveats are still important, but not a show-stopper.

Comment: Fair enough, what would you recommend over the other answers? In your opinion would you use an inner select or user variables?

Comment: @Petah: I'm not sure I want to answer that ;-)  Variables work, and they can dramatically speed up some queries. If it works once for a given query, it will continue to work (although I guess that there's a small chance that different MySQL versions will handle the same query differently).  However, using variables is non-standard SQL, so it's not portable.  The sub-query route is arguably a more robust long term solution, at the potential expense of execution speed. So ultimately, it depends on your requirements. Sorry for sitting on the fence!

Comment: No, thank you for being objective and informative. However, for arguments sake, say I am using MySQL 5.1.49, and I will never change. Would you still sit on the fence?

Comment: Sorry, and on a side note, what is the precision level of variables? As currently, on the application level I round everything `< 0 & > -1%` to `-1%` and everything `> 0 & < 1%` to `1%`

Comment: @Petah: In that case, I'd use variables.  As for their data types or precision, I don't know.  The docs don't appear to give much away, but I too would be interested to know.

Comment: @Petah: I suggest you try all answers (and measure them) with your data (and with larger test tables), before deciding which to choose. You can always keep all options as alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

Use an inner select (it's like a temporary view) and select from that. This should work:

```
SELECT
  customer_id,
  customer_name,
  1_year_average_spend,
  3_month_average_spend,
  if (1_year_average_spend = 0, "N/A", (3_month_average_spend / 1_year_average_spend) - 1) AS 3_month_performance
FROM (SELECT
  customer_id,
  customer_name,
  AVG(IF(DATE(CONCAT(year_of_spend, "-", month_of_spend, "-01")) >=
    DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR, "%Y-%m-01"), spend_amount, NULL)) AS 1_year_average_spend,
  AVG(IF(DATE(CONCAT(year_of_spend, "-", month_of_spend, "-01")) >=
    DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH, "%Y-%m-01"), spend_amount, NULL)) AS 3_month_average_spend)
FROM customer_spends 
GROUP BY customer_id, customer_name ) x
```

Answer (score 1):

Would `NULL` do as the `N/A` value? If so, you could apply `NULLIF()` to the denominator like this:

```
a / NULLIF(b, 0) - 1
```

`NULLIF` returns `NULL` if its first argument is equal to the second argument. And if an operand is `NULL`, the entire expression evaluates to `NULL`.

Like @Bohemian, I, too, suggest using a subselect. Here's the complete query:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
  customer_id,
  customer_name,
  1_year_average_spend,
  3_month_average_spend,
  3_month_average_spend / NULLIF(1_year_average_spend, 0) - 1 AS change
FROM (
  SELECT
    customer_id,
    customer_name,
    AVG(IF(
         DATE(CONCAT(year_of_spend, "-", month_of_spend, "-01")) >=
             DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR, "%Y-%m-01"),
         spend_amount,
         NULL
    )) AS 1_year_average_spend,
    AVG(IF(
         DATE(CONCAT(year_of_spend, "-", month_of_spend, "-01")) >=
             DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH, "%Y-%m-01"),
         spend_amount,
         NULL
    )) AS 3_month_average_spend
  FROM customer_spends
  GROUP BY customer__id
) s
```

Comment: A little confusing with the whole `if null or null = any or null if a = b etc` but after I got my head around it, it sounds good.

Answer (score 0):

Getting rid of `IF()`, `DATE()` and `CONCAT()` function calls. Your query, as it is now, has to scan the whole `customer_spends` table and check those complex conditions for ALL rows, even if they are 10 years old data.

This will also use an index of `(year_of_spend, month_of_spend)` or `(customer_id, year_of_spend, month_of_spend)` to speed up the query:

```
SELECT c.customer_id
     , c.customer_name
     , 1_year_average_spend
     , 3_month_average_spend
     , CASE WHEN 1_year_average_spend = 0
              THEN 'N/A'
              ELSE (3_month_average_spend / 1_year_average_spend) - 1
       END AS percent_difference
FROM
    customer AS c
  JOIN
    ( SELECT customer_id
           , AVG(spend_amount) AS 1_year_average_spend 
      FROM customer_spends 
      WHERE (year_of_spend, month_of_spend) >=
               ( YEAR(CUR_DATE() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
               , MONTH(CUR_DATE() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
               )
      GROUP BY customer_id
    ) AS grp1year
    ON grp1year.customer_id = c.customer_id
  LEFT JOIN
    ( SELECT customer_id
           , AVG(spend_amount) AS 3_month_average_spend
      FROM customer_spends 
      WHERE (year_of_spend, month_of_spend) >=
               ( YEAR(CUR_DATE() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
               , MONTH(CUR_DATE() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
               )
      GROUP BY customer_id
    ) AS grp3month
    ON grp3month.customer_id = c.customer_id
```